# What is the equivalent configuration for setting size limit by heap percentage (maxBytesLocalHeap) in Ehcache 3.x?

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-3

There was a config called `maxBytesLocalHeap` in Ehcache `2.x` where we could enter a heap percentage value. I couldn't find an equivalent in `3.x`, but there's nothing about *deprecation* in release notes or migration guides.

Is there a way to specify Ehcache heap size by JVM heap percentage in versions `3.x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can limit it by percentage. The only place I was able to find indicating that it was deprecated was [**this one**](https://documentation.softwareag.com/terracotta/terracotta_4310/bigmemory-max/webhelp/index.html#page/bigmemory-max-webhelp/co-srch_making_cache_searchable.html).

**You can however**, do this by the number of entries or byte size:

> [image]

#### See also:

- [Ehcache Tiering Options](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.3/tiering.html#heap-tier)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same confusion. The setting itself isn't deprecated, just the use of memory units in the value.

The ehcache xsd states:

```
    <xs:documentation>
      DEPRECATED: The use of memory units (such as 'B', 'kB' or 'MB') for heap resources is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    </xs:documentation>
```

The `DEPRECATED` seems to confuse IntelliJ into thinking the entire element is deprecated.

As long as the value for heap has no units, it is treated as "number of entries", which is not deprecated.